# Why slanted bodies slip, what is causing the acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, acceleration, torque

Let the body be a ladder, it is held at slanted position with base on the floor. If it is leaved, with zero velocity, then why it's base slips backward when the upper part of the ladder is falling down, there is no force being applied in that direction.

Comment: think about the center of mass of the ladder relative to its base

Comment: @Cursed what do you mean by that, I didn't got it

Comment: by definition: an object topples when its center of mass is outside the bass of the object (bass being the points of contact with the ground)

Comment: @Cursed I am not asking why body falls (topples), but why base slips while body falls?

Comment: The upper part of the ladder has a velocity in the -y direction and this velocity has a component along the length of the ladder. Since ladder is a rigid body, this component of the upper part of the ladder makes it to move along the length of the ladder (that is inside the ground), but ladder can't penetrate into the floor and hence has to move along the floor backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no force acting on the center of mass that points in that direction, since the only two present forces are the floor reaction and gravitational force, so the sum of them determines a force directed vertically. Since the floor reaction is not applied to the center of mass, the ladder undergoes a rotation. You can see what is happening in the following picture: [image]

Roughly speaking, the ladder truly slipped on the left, but also the upper part (on the right of the center of mass) "moved" right. So the motion that you are talking about is only an illusion, and is actually a rotation. If the floor didn't stop the ladder fall (for example the ladder is on the edge of a rooftop, ignoring its interaction with the very edge at the moment in which the ladder is horizontal), the center of mass would always follow a straight, vertical line, while the ladder would keep rotating around it.

Comment: I got it right 3 times out of 5. Sorry, I know my english is bad.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, COM is not moving. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The ladder, wall, and floor form a right triangle.  The hypotenuse is the ladder, whose length is fixed.  For the top of the ladder to slide down, [Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) tells us the bottom of the ladder must slide out.